# Bootstrap grid system with table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'd like to have table like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to do this with bootstrap grid system, but it doesn't work...here is my code. Maybe the problem is with class container? It is correct to put  div there?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<div class="container">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-sx-6">Avanced Time targetting</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">Midnight<br/>12am</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">4am</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">8am</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">Noon<br/>12pm</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">4pm</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">8pm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-sx-6">
            <span>Monday</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button>All days</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>Morning</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>9-5</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>Evening</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>Custom</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>Clear</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>Restore</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: No. it is not correct way to do so. Container must be outside of table tag

Comment: No, it's not correct. You must respect the following architecture for your table with bootstrap :
.table > thead/tbody > tr > td/th, check the css here : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **HTML** code is correct but you need to put the **container** div before the table.

Here is some of basic understanding about  [**bootstrap grid system**](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php).

Comment: Thanks, I have understood this basic but in this case why I can't put .container class in table tag and .row in row tag?

Comment: Wrapping everything in the conatiner div will manage the width of the page and side padding. Using the row div will ensure that your table are layed out the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

The *container div* must be **outside** the table in order for it to *align* correctly. Furthermore, the structure of your table will align *perfectly* when you use the **theader**, **tbody** and **tfooter** tags in your table along with the *th/td* *tags*.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Good point. Now I edited it and revised it to make it  have a better answer format.